# Why is Windows able to rename a folder quicker than it is able to delete one?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems

In the work I do, I often have to rename and delete folders.

Shift-deleting a folder goes pretty quickly - perhaps 10-20 seconds for 1-2GB, while renaming the same folder occurs instantly.

My understanding is that when I shift-delete a folder, Windows is going through the file index and saying 'space x to y is no longer occupied by these files'.

Naively, I figured that Windows would have to do a similar process for a folder rename - changing the windows path on the file index.

Can someone perhaps give a high level overview of what's going on with windows when it renames and deletes folders?

Answer (score 6):

Renaming a folder (or file) requires:

- checking that the new name does not already exist in the parent folder;
- overwriting the name in the appropriate directory entry.

No subfolders or files in the renamed directory tree are affected in any way.

Deleting a directory requires:

- traversing the directory tree to find each file in each subdirectory;
- checking each file is not in use and deleting it by patching its directory and marking the space it used as available in the disc allocation table;
- once all the files have been removed from a subdirectory, deleting the directory and making its space available, as for a file;
- continuing this process until eventually the original directory is deleted.

The time to delete a directory therefore depends on the number of files and subdirectories, and the size and degree of fragmentation of each.

On the other hand, moving a directory to a different disc or partition requires the creation and copying of each file in each subdirectory, as well as the deletion of the source directory.